# How to chain multiple regex Patterns?

Tags: java

I have some precompiled regex patterns,

```java
private static final Pattern[] REGEX = new Pattern[] {
        Pattern.compile("foo"),
        Pattern.compile("bar"),
        Pattern.compile("baz"),
        // n more
};
```

Now, I would like to use multiple matchers for replacing on the same string,

```java
String s = "foo0bar1baz2";
s = REGEX[1].matcher(REGEX[0].matcher(query).replaceFirst("abc")).replaceFirst("xyz");
```

This gets unwieldy as more and more matchers are added. Looping all the time leads to too much boilerplate. Is there a builder or stream or any other better way to do this?

EDIT: Not all patterns need to be applied all the time, only some subset. Therefore, a chain pattern like builder or stream would be more desirable.

Comment: BTW do you really need regular expressions? The posted examples do not need it

Comment: I don't get why looping should be more boiler-plate than what you have for just three patterns. Stream handling can replace the loop but brings other problems.

Comment: @user85421 The examples are for illustrative purposes only. The actual regular expressions are much more complex.

Comment: @queeg I will have many more patterns. Looping is more boilerplate because not all patterns need to be applied all the time.

Comment: I have added that to my answer.

Comment: continuation? [How to match two different regexes and replace with different strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77890403/85421) -- seems like you are not sure what is needed...  [XYProblem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/141148)?

Comment: @ManakBisht not the loop is boilerplate. It is the unneeded patterns. How do you identify when you need which pattern? You can exclude them from the loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### use a loop

In case you really need multiple regexes, you can use a loop:

```java
record Replacement(Pattern pattern, String replaceWith){}
private static final List<Replacement> REGEX = List.of() {
        new Replacement(Pattern.compile("foo"),"abc"),
        new Replacement(Pattern.compile("bar"),"xyz"),
        // n more
};
```

```java
String processed = query;
for(Replacement entry : REGEX){
    processed = entry.pattern().matcher(query).replaceFirst(entry.replaceWith());
}
```

I am using a `Replacement` record to save the `Pattern` to match along with the `String` to replace it with. In case you want something more powerful, you could use a `Function` instead of the `String` or add a `Predicate` or similar to test whether to replace it.

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77889259/10871900) for that approach along with a full example of it.

### combine the regexes

However, this approach still needs to apply each regex on each string.

Alternatively, you could combine your regex to a single regex with named groups which allow you to find out which part of the regex triggered:

```java
private static final Pattern REGEX = Pattern.compile("(?<foo>foo)(?<bar>bar)");
private static final Map<String, String> REPLACEMENTS = Map.of("foo", "abc", "bar", "xyz");
```

```java
REGEX.matcher(query)
    .replaceAll(result ->
        result
            .namedGroups()//get groups
            .entrySet()
            .stream()
            //.filter(e->e.getValue()==1)//you could check whether that group is at the beginning
            .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
            .filter(REPLACEMENTS::containsKey)//only if you actually have a matching entry in REPLACEMENTS
            .map(k->REPLACEMENTS.get(k)//look up what to replace it with
            .orElse(result.group())//if the group is not found, don't replace anything (i.e. replace the String with itself)
    );
```

This approach assumes that each group starts at the beginning of the regex. When it finds a match, it gets the name of the group, looks up what it should be replaced with and replaces it accordingly.

Note that this logic may replace the same regex multiple times. If you don't want that, you could store the group names that have been replaced already and skip them (using another `filter`).

### use a Trie

In case you don't need Regex capabilities and just want to replace fixed strings, you can make use of the Trie data structure in order to do that task efficiently. This would allow you to search through the elements without checking each query against the full string each time. This could be an improvement with many strings.

### Your edit

You wrote

> Not all patterns need to be applied all the time, only some subset. Therefore, a chain pattern like builder or stream would be more desirable.

If you can find a criterion which pattern to apply, you can add an `if` to the loop, add an additional `filter` to the `Stream` or just use a different `REPLACEMENTS` map containing only the group names you want to replace.

#### programmatically

However, if you want to do all of it without an object storing what to replace in what way, you can just add a method:

```java
String replaceFirstRegex(String query, int regexIndex, String replacement){
    REGEX[regexIndex].matcher(query).replaceFirst(replacement);
}
```

```java
String processed = query;
processed = replaceFirstRegex(processed, 0, "abc");
processed = replaceFirstRegex(processed, 1, "def");
```

##### with chaining

In case you really want to make something that can be chained, just create a record containing the `String` and the method:

```java
record StringToReplace(String toReplace){
    String replaceFirstRegex(int regexIndex, String replacement){
        REGEX[regexIndex].matcher(toReplace).replaceFirst(replacement);
    }
}
```

```java
String replaced = new StringToReplace(query)
    .replaceFirstRegex(0, "abc")
    .replaceFirstRegex(1, "xyz")
    //m more
    .toReplace();
```

Comment: `Map` is not the best data structure here: 1) it does not express what code is doing - you don't want to map search patterns (`Pattern` or `String`) to a replacement; 2) it will not allow the same search pattern (`Pattern` or `String`) two times (using `equals`;) 3) there is no guarantee about the order of entries (can be relevant if replacing the same pattern or chained pattern/replacement)

Comment: I now addressed this in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

it's quite easy: create a record/pojo that contains pattern and replacement string, create an array of all couples that you need, loop over the array it using pattern an replace string

```
package org.example;

import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class MultiplePattern {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Replace[] replaces = new Replace[]{
            new Replace("foo", "abc"),
            new Replace("bar", "xyz"),
            new Replace("baz", "123")
            // n more
    };

    String input = "foo0bar1baz2";
    String output = input;
    for (Replace replace : replaces) {
        output = replace.pattern().matcher(output).replaceFirst(replace.replacement());
    }
    System.out.println("Input: " + input);
    System.out.println("Output: " + output);
}

record Replace(Pattern pattern, String replacement) {
    public Replace(String pattern, String replacement) {
        this(Pattern.compile(pattern), replacement);
    }
}
}
```

that's the console output:

```
Input: foo0bar1baz2
Output: abc0xyz11232
```

note:

> record is a Java 14+ type, if you want to use lower version you need to create a simple pojo